# SSRS minus first two dates as the header

Tags: sql-server, ssrs

I have a SSRS report that has one column called startime that is listed in mm:dd:yyyy hh:mm:ss format.  For the header of this column I want to minus the first date from the second date to give me an idea of how long is between the two dates, this will likely be in minutes.

I don't need a running total, I just need to be able to minus the first date from the second date in the column will be good enough.  I have bee playing around with the following but its throwing up some strange results.

```
=Fields!StartTime.Value - Previous(Fields!StartTime.Value)
```

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What does "strange results" mean? While simple subtraction works with the old datetime types (e.g. GETDATE()-1), [you shouldn't do this](https://sqlblog.org/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations). Does SSRS support any of the DATEADD() or DATEDIFF() functions? If not, can't you change the query to provide this information?

Comment: It means in some cases I got high positive numbers and in others negative numbers, which don't add up if doing a subtraction.  It does support the DATEADD() and DATEDIFF() functions, however I don't know how to reference only the first two items of data in the column.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh. You want to ***subtract*** something. Now I get it.

Answer (score 1):

Can you do the calculations in the dataset the report uses? May have an easier time doing that then building the expression needed to calculate the column for SSRS

Comment: Yes I think I will look at doing it that way instead.